# Asyncronous Entity framework DB access fails with exceptions (ASP .NET core)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, entity-framework-core

I'm implemeting a cookie authentication module as a middleware in my ASP .NET core application. I receive an error *"InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."* when 2 requests come almost at the same time (in the function CheckToken). I believe every request should receive a separate DB context, so I don't understand why is this error occurring.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    // ...


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // ...
    app.UseTeamAuthentication();
    // ...
```

**Middleware**

```
namespace Team
{
    public static class TeamExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseTeamAuthentication(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<TeamAuthentication>();
        }
    }

    public class TeamAuthentication
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;

        public TeamAuthentication(RequestDelegate _next, ApplicationDbContext _db)
        {
            next = _next;
            db = _db;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            bool Authenticated = false;
            bool Login = (context.Request.Path == "/Login");
            string TokenContent = context.Request.Cookies["t"];

            if (!Login && TokenContent != null)
            {
                int UserID = await Security.CheckToken(db, TokenContent);
                if (UserID > 0)
                {
                    Authenticated = true;
                }
            }

            if (Login || Authenticated)
            {
                await next.Invoke(context);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                if (context.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] != "XMLHttpRequest")
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("No access!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CheckToken**

```
public async static Task<int> CheckToken(ApplicationDbContext db, string Content)
{
    var token = await db.Token.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Content == Content);
    if (token != null)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now < token.Expiry)
        {
            token.Expiry = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return token.UserID;
        }
        else
        {
            db.Token.Remove(token);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not ask for `ApplicationDbContext` in constructor. This will lead to having only one DbContext instance for all request and to errors like your one.

Instead, get separate DbContext for each request (more precisely - once for each DI Scope) with this code inside `Invoke` method:

```
var db = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are injecting DB context into middleware. But I guess middleware is created once per application not per request. That's why all requests get the same DB context inside middleware.

Comment: Well, if that was the case, wouldn't (functional) DB access in the middleware be impossible? How would middleware authentication ever work in such circumstance?

Comment: I think it's possible. Try to add dependency into `Invoke` method, not constructor, like `public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ApplicationDbContext db)`